# How to add tab icon (change title text decoration) for read only files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimetext, readonly

I moved to Sublime Text 3 from PSPad and I am very happy with it, but there are few things that I do not like. In `PSPad` I was locking files (edit protection) so I was not able to edit them by mistake. This function is in Sublime Text as well but I am missing there some notification that the file is locked/read only. Something like lock icon beside the file name on the tab. Or even different text decoration (different color, underlined text-just anything). And maybe a shortcut would be nice (in `PSPad` it was `Ctrl+L`). Thanks.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit`.

Comment: How do you lock a file in sublime so that it can't be edited?

Comment: Right click the tab and select `Toggle Readonly`

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem. In addition Toggle Readonly is not a default feature but a plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized that. I have installed the plugins a while ago.